# Rails 4 string interpolation in raw SQL request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

What would be the best way of rewriting this query without interpolation?

```
def case_joins(type)
  subquery = <<-SQL.squish
    SELECT id FROM cases c2
    WHERE c2.title_id = titles.id AND c2.value = 0 AND c2.type = '#{type}'
    ORDER BY c2.created_at DESC LIMIT 1       
  SQL
  "LEFT OUTER JOIN cases ON cases.title_id = titles.id AND cases.value = 0 AND cases.type = '#{type}' AND cases.id = (#{subquery})"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to avoid interpolation of variables, which is dangerous since its open to SQL injection. I would simply join onto the cases selected from the subquery instead of putting the subquery into the `WHERE` conditions. This does involve interpolation, but only of AR-generated SQL. I would also implement it as a scope to leverage AR scope chaining:

```
class Title < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.case_joins(type)
    case_query = Case.from("cases c").where(c: {title_id: title_id, value: 0, type: type}).order('c.created_at DESC').limit(1)
    joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN (#{case_query.to_sql}) cases ON cases.title_id = titles.id")
  end
end
```

This way, you can chain the scope to others like so:

```
Title.where(attribute1: value1).case_joins("typeA")
```

(Note that removed the superfluous `WHERE` conditions in the outer `SELECT`.)

Comment: This looks good, however I need to assign a different name to the table in  subquery (`case_query`). Can I do this using `WHERE`?

Comment: @Pav31 I've edited the answer with aliasing on the subquery -- you just need to use the `from` scope, and then edit the `where` hash to match.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, though I needed to make minor alteration to your method by adding `select(:id)` before `limit(1)', and removing `self` since I'm declaring it outside of the model.

Comment: Excellent, if it worked for you, could you go ahead and accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to infer what the rest of your code looks like, but I presume `titles` is being used in a query further up your call stack.

If you were to use ActiveRecord instead of native SQL, you could do something like this:

```
def case_joins(scope, title_id, type)
  ids = Case.where(title_id: title_id, value: 0, type: type)
             .order('created_at desc').limit(1).pluck(:id)

  scope.joins('left outer join cases on cases.title_id = titles.id')
             .where(value: 0, type: type, id: ids)
end
```

`scope` here is the current AR query you are modifying.

This is off the top of my head, so I'm not sure if the AR syntax above is correct, but it does avoid the need to interpolate SQL and also uses scoping.

To be honest, though, it's not all that much more readable than native SQL, and so YMMV.  It does at least mean that (apart from the join) you're not encoding SQL in your code.

Comment: if you would use `.select(:id)` instead of `.pluck(:id)` then there is only one roundtrip to the database server instead of two; and may be your only option if you have a very large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Here is modification of @eirikir's answer, that works the same way as method in question.

```
def case_joins(type)
  case_query = Case.from("cases c").where('c.title_id = titles.id AND c.value = 0 AND c.type = ?', type).order('c.created_at DESC').select(:id).limit(1)
 "LEFT OUTER JOIN cases ON cases.title_id = titles.id AND cases.id = (#{case_query.to_sql})"
end
```