# Provide prepared statement in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am using rails-4.2.1 and is trying to fetch data from two tables subjects and elective_subjects table in a single query. As rails 4 does not support UNION , I wrote a raw sql query. I want to search by name in both tables. My code is given below

```
query = "(SELECT id as id, name as name, reference as reference from subjects where name like '#{search}') UNION (SELECT id as id, name as name, null as reference from elective_subjects where name like '#{search}')"

@subjects =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

It is working but when I provide ' in my search the query breaks. So how can I make it a prepared statement. So that sql injection can be avoided

Comment: what do you mean, "the query breaks"?

Comment: It generates a mysql exception when there is a single quotes in the search variable

Comment: why not try `\"` instead of `'`. some systems are stingy with what the database allows in the where clause

Comment: also refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455508/rails-4-string-interpolation-in-raw-sql-request

Answer (score 3):

This question is super old and no cares anymore, but I think it is a valid question, so here's the answer:

```rb
query = "(SELECT id as id, name as name, reference as reference from subjects where name like $1) 
         UNION
         (SELECT id as id, name as name, null as reference from elective_subjects where name like $1)"

binds = [ActiveRecord::Relation::QueryAttribute.new('name', search, ActiveRecord::Type::Text.new)]

result = ApplicationRecord.connection.exec_query(query, 'SQL', binds, prepare: true)

@subjects = result.rows
```

That's how you create and use a prepared statement in rails.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by escaping the search string using following statement.

```
search = Mysql2::Client.escape(search)
```

Comment: Congrats on figuring this out. JFYI, you only masked the problem. This code is still vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: can you please provide a better option